# Specify Internet Connection When requesting a URL in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, wifi, cellular-network

I'm developing an app that is using Wi-Fi to connect to a network that doesn't have internet, although there is cellular signal. I was wondering is there a way to make the app use the cellular network for some requests or `NSURL` s and the `Wi-Fi` for others? and if there is how can I do that?

Thank you

Comment: Device will use Wifi if it is available, if not then it will check if user allows apps to use cellular network. If not then you won't be able to use "cellular network". However if user allows then device should automatically fall back and use available connection (in your case cellular network).

Comment: What about making use of the Reachability classes? https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability   This supports ARC. Or grab the one from Apple (that doesnt support ARC last time i checked.)